# way to import java program to flash?

Tags: java, actionscript-3, flash

I'm making a flash game and need to use part of a java program. Is there a way to import the java program into flash? Only a section of the game will be using the java program, so I don't want to import the flash part into java...

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.flashmagazine.com/tutorials/detail/getting_across_to_flash_with_java/ Does this sound like it would be helpful? It's an older article but might still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You may port a java part if you have sources of your java program and the logic of the program can be handled by action script

Thanks,
Cyril